# Null Pointer when using GSON

Tags: json, parsing, nullpointerexception, gson

Hi guys I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.. I was hoping to get a fresh pair of eyes on it.

My JSON looks as such:

```
{
  “EventDocVersion”:”2006-05-05”,
  “EventDocId”:”ABC”,
  “CustomerId”:”527185744892”,
  “Events”:[{
    “EventType”:“HITReviewable”,
    “EventTimestamp”:“2005-01-31T235959Z”,
    “HITTypeId”:“3ZYIH7REHFTJ0AUXF6IE6EXWY5V1O5”,
    “HITId”:“3LAZVA75NI96Z33B4ICBRHEA9FQ2OM”
  }]
}
```

and here is how I'm parsing it:

```
JsonObject messageBody = new JsonParser().parse(rawMessage.getBody()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray events = messageBody.getAsJsonArray("Events");
System.err.println("MessageBody: [" + messageBody + "]");
System.err.println("We have Events: [" + events + "]");
```

The print statements are printing:

```
MessageBody: [{"“EventDocVersion”":"”2006-05-05”","“EventDocId”":"”ABC”","“CustomerId”":"”527185744892”","“Events”":[{"“EventType”":"“HITReviewable”","“EventTimestamp”":"“2005-01-31T235959Z”","“HITTypeId”":"“3ZYIH7REHFTJ0AUXF6IE6EXWY5V1O5”","“HITId”":"“3LAZVA75NI96Z33B4ICBRHEA9FQ2OM”"}]}]

We have Events: [null]
```

The funny part is I can't even do

```
messageBody.getAsJsonString("EventDocId");
```

that will return null for me as well..

Comment: What do your prints tell you

Comment: added the prints. forgot to add them

Comment: Do you see the double quotation marks everywhere? That's not right

Comment: thought that might be the case.. I can't seem to figure out why gson adds quotes next to my quotes..

Comment: hoooooooly shinanigans the quotes are wierd quotes which is why its not getting recognized by gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes you are using are wrong, change your quotes `“”` to `""`, then the code you have should work. If using those kind of quotes then maybe `messageBody.getAsJsonArray("“Events”");` would work, same goes with EventDocId.

Answer (score 0):

“ and " are two different characters. mac users be aware.

Comment: Considering json usually comes from a server of some kind, this is not specific to mac users